# Can DIFF command be used for two URLs?

Tags: unix, diff

I have two URLs and I am trying to find a list of differences between them using the `diff` command. 
It is returning an error:

> A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: What is the command exactly that you run?

Comment: Do you want to diff the URLs or the pages behind them?